# Eclipse eclipse.ini XXMaxPermSize

Tags: eclipse, jvm

I found in eclipse.ini

`openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m`

IFAIK XXMaxPermSize is parameter of JVM(MaxPermSize specifies the the maximum size for the permanent generation heap, a heap that holds objects such as classes and methods). Why need this parameter repeate 2 times? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that the eclipse.ini is organized into different sections for different options, and that that parameter is specified in multiple options, probably showsplash and product (even though you didn't post it)

Comment: Complete eclipse.ini - original as downloaded                                 -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

Comment: yup, you have -startup -product and -showsplash, these are your eclipse options